# Acrobat Reader shared review editing in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I like to know if there is any possibilities to edit the shared review of Adobe Acrobat Reader in PHP.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Acrobat/8.0/Professional/help.html?content=WS8F17CB6D-B39D-4cf6-8060-7907C1AC53F7.html

Now I am able to give the comments and able to publish too but my requirement is when one user comment one thing then another user will edit the same one. Current system doesn't allow this. Is there any tool available or any libraries?

Please help me to find the out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Could you pls. elaborate your question ?
If there are multiple reviewers [You have assigned/mailed multiple people] to a document then they can reply to each-others comments...there should not be any problem.